# How can I use BoringSSL in Linux that already has OpenSSL installed?

Tags: c, makefile, openssl, boringssl

I am able to compile BoringSSL on Ubuntu and created libssl.a and libcrypto.a. In Makefile I have changed `-L` path to point to those library location and `-lssl -lcrypto` to specify the library name. However my machine already has OpenSSL installed, so looks like in this case it is the OpenSSL libs getting picked up as always because the libraries have exact same name.

If there any other way to enforce OS to use BoringSSL other than completely remove or disable OpenSSL and try?

Comment: If you have `-L` pointed to the directory where BoringSSL is built, it will always use BoringSSL instead of the system SSL.

Comment: Not necessarily, @S.S.Anne.  If the linker is looking specifically for shared libraries, rejecting static ones, then it will pass right over any `libssl.a` or `libcrypto.a` it may come across.  There are many more details and nuances, depending on exactly what the OP means and is trying to achieve.  We really need more information (in the form of a [mre], please, keye) to answer the question.

Comment: you could try  passing the pull paths to these `.a` files on the gcc command line:   something like:  `g++  main.cc  /full/path/libssl.a  /full/path/libcrypto.a`  ... note it doesn't use `-L` nor `-l`

Comment: @S.S.Anne thanks. it works on my setup. By specifying `-L <path to *.a>` and `-lssl -lcrypto -lpthread`, without `-lpthread` there are compiling errors from `crypto_free* ` functions.

Comment: @keye See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `-L` pointed to the directory where BoringSSL is built, it will always use BoringSSL instead of the system SSL (except if the linker is searching for shared libraries only, as John Bollinger points out).

You'll also need to pass `-pthread` to the compiler as it can't implicitly pull in the POSIX thread library with a static library like it can with a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the library path with the shared libraries is not in the search paths of the linker and then the -L search path will be used and picks up the static libraries.

Alternatively try adding -Bstatic flag after -L to notify linker to use static libraries only.